# Hibernate L2 Cache on cluster

Tags: hibernate, second-level-cache

Q1:
Am I right that only this vendors support Hibernate L2 cache on cluster?

- Terracotta for Hibernate (comercial)
- SwarmCache (not released since 2003)
- JBoss Cache 1.x
- JBoss Cache 2

Q2: 
Are there are any alternatives to Hibernate L2 cache? (Maybe some DB caching?)

Comment: Terracotta is OSS the same as JBoss not sure why you listed as commercial

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Q1. EhCache works very well as the Hibernate L2 Cache, distributed.
We are using this for our project.

---

Q2. Several caches are possible.

- All database are already doing a lot of caching internally, so don't worry about this part.

> However, the problem with the database
>   cache is that it is physically on the
>   database server, so each query
>   involves a network call (latency,
>   bandwith ..). That's the whole point
>   of the caches on the application
>   server.

---

- The Hibernate L2 cache has some specifics:

  - very easy to work with (no code, little configuration)
  - conceptually at the entity level (which is pretty fine-grained, we sometimes need to cache bigger grains, to make less database requests),
  - working by id or collection (for example, caching a query result is deactivated by default, because it is impossible to make it useful in the general case).

---

- When the Hibernate L2 is inappropriate, we use the same EhCache library to cache data (that is not exactly entities). Examples of use-cases:

  - when a table is **big (record length and number)**, memory usage would not permit to cache it completely, but caching only three fields for all records is okay. It could be that these fields are the ones accessed often, or immutable...
  - when we have many read accesses to the cache, and each would trigger a **computation** (on L2 cache) given the entities we have : the computation result can be stored in the cache. (typical exemple where the computation requires details from other tables, but the details are not used in the final result, so the cache doesn't store these details)
  - when entities in a table are logically grouped by **categories**, and we want to request and cache one category at a time, instead of the regular L2 Cache policy that would be one entity at a time.

> In a distributed context, this often
>   translates into invalidating a
>   category at a time when one of their
>   entities is modified, which is functionally
>   logical for us (and essential for
>   performance, as otherwise we would
>   have to invalidate all of these
>   entities ; this is because the cache
>   invalidates a whole region, or a
>   specific object, but in
>   between you have to loop which is bad for performance)

And others I'm sure ...

So this case is not closely database-related, it usually doesn't store our Hibernate entities. We put it in the Business Tier (and not the Data Access or Daos), make it available directly to business codes. Note that for us, it is not a transparent cache, but a call to an explicit business service (responsible for this cache : loading it if the data is not present, invalidating as needed) that does operations or deliver values.

> A fun Threading issue in this cache : because this cache is accessed by our hundred web threads, it needs to be thread-safe. You probably know why a thread-safe value is either immutable or cloned at each call (which often is a performance problem). So all our business caches use immutable objects, and performance is great.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Infinispan (evolution of JBoss Cache) as 2nd level cache provider!][1]

[1]: See http://infinispan.blogspot.com/2009/10/infinispan-based-hibernate-cache.html

Answer (score 1):

EhCache has a distributed mode, but I'm not sure if that's supported with Hibernate. I don't see why it shouldn't work, though.

Did you omit JBossCache 3 for some specific reason?

Comment: No, I simply didn't know about it =). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[hibernate-redis](https://github.com/debop/hibernate-redis) lib would be perfect choice. It's a Redis based cache.

Why Redis? it's blazing fast, works in cloud and has ready-cloud solution like [AWS Elasticache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/), so you don't need to manage it by yourself.